# Extension to convert images to .webp format is not working

Tags: typo3, webp, typo3-12.x

I am working on a local Composer based installation of TYPO3 v12.4 (I cannot update to v13) and have installed the extension ['plan2net/webp'](https://github.com/plan2net/webp/blob/master/README.md) to convert all of my images to `.webp`-format. But for some reason the extension is not converting any images at all.

Here is what I tried to make the extension work:

1. Add webp to generally allowed file formats:

   ```
   $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext'] .= ',webp';
   ```
2. Installed the extension via

   ```
   ddev composer require "plan2net/webp"
   ```
3. Checked in the backend module that the extension is installed and stable.
4. Following the extension manual, I have then flushed TYPO3 and PHP Cache and cleared the processed files in the Maintenance module. Also updated the Database Structure**. At this point** I would expect the extension to generate a copy of each image and save it as `webp`. However, this is not the case if I check the files within the processed folder.
5. Then I added this to my .htaccess file within :

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.*)\.(png|gif|jpe?g)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.webp -f
    RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.webp [L,T=image/webp]
   </IfModule>
   ```

   And yes, mod_rewrite.c is enabled.
6. At the bottom of the htaccess file I added:

   ```
   <IfModule mod_headers.c>
       <FilesMatch "\.(png|gif|jpe?g)$">
           Header append Vary Accept
       </FilesMatch>
   </IfModule>
   ```
7. Last step was to flush TYPO3 and PHP Cache and to clear the processed files again.

   What am I missing?

Comment: have you checked for `Image Processing`? (in the Environment module) 
you need `grahicsmagic` or `imagemagic` to work on any images.

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ Yes, I can see there that imagemagic is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your system match the [requirements](https://github.com/plan2net/webp/blob/master/README.md#requirements) for webp?

> You can either use the installed Imagemagick or GraphicsMagick you
> already use for TYPO3 image manipulation if it supports webp (see
> below) or you can use any other external binary available on your
> server (e.g. cwebp).
>
> You can test the support of GraphicsMagick with e.g.:
>
> `gm version | grep WebP`
>
> (should return `yes`)
>
> or using ImageMagick with e.g.:
>
> `convert version | grep webp`
>
> (should return a list of supported formats including `webp`)

You can check the support of `webp` via `phpinfo()`:
[image: Screenshot display ImageMagick part of phpinfo()-output]

---

**DDEV**

In the case of older ddev, you must add `webimage_extra_packages: [webp]` to your config.yaml.

Imagemagick and gd both seem to include webp support out of the box in recent versions of ddev.

https://github.com/ddev/ddev/issues/1780

Answer (score 0):

@LoreenT. if you look into your assets and processed folders, do there for real exist .webp copies of your images? Then the processing is working.
However the most important thing: It seems like you are using ddev which is usally nginx and not apache. So in case its nginx, your htaccess rules will be ignored in ddev. But you might just update your ddev, the latest versions already inlcude the correct .webp routing within their nginx config.